# Objects not destroy after wallpaper preview

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I am writing live wallpaper for Android, and I have one problem:
After wallpaper preview garbage collector do not clear objects from memory, that's why allocated memory inreases each time when the user want to see preview or change some options.
Does anybody know how to fix it, how to clear memory? (stopSelf and System.gc not working).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to recycle your bitmap?